# Java Card game program stop in midway

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pooo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int card1;
      int card2;
      int card3;
      int card4;
      int card5;
      int numSuit1;
      int numSuit2;
      int numSuit3;
      int numSuit4;
      int numSuit5;
      int temp;
      int winner = 0;
      int counter = 0;
      int idcounter = 0;
      int frcounter = 0;
      String YN = "EMP";
      String Finish = "";
      String Selection = "EMP";
      String Selection1 = "EMP";
      String Selection2 = "EMP";
      String Selection3 = "EMP";
      String Selection4 = "EMP";
      String Selection5 = "EMP";
      String Selection6 = "EMP";
      String Selection7 = "EMP";
      String Selection8 = "EMP";
      String Selection9 = "EMP";
      String RES = "";
      String Suit1 = "";
      String Suit2 = "";
      String Suit3 = "";
      String Suit4 = "";
      String Suit5 = "";
      String card1s = "";
      String card2s = "";
      String card3s = "";
      String card4s = "";
      String card5s = "";

      Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

      while ((!YN.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) & (winner == 0)) {
         counter = counter + 1;
         idcounter = 0; // counter for identification

         // pick 5 random numbers for cards
         card1 = (int) (Math.random() * 13) + 1;
         card2 = (int) (Math.random() * 13) + 1;
         card3 = (int) (Math.random() * 13) + 1;
         card4 = (int) (Math.random() * 13) + 1;
         card5 = (int) (Math.random() * 13) + 1;

         // Order from smallest to largest
         int cards[] = { card1, card2, card3, card4, card5 };
         boolean fixed = false;
         while (fixed == false) {
            fixed = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < cards.length - 1; i++) {

               if (cards[i] > cards[i + 1]) {
                  temp = cards[i + 1];
                  cards[i + 1] = cards[i];
                  cards[i] = temp;
                  fixed = false;
               }
            }
         }

         // Generating suits for the 5 cards
         numSuit1 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
         numSuit2 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
         numSuit3 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
         numSuit4 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
         numSuit5 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;

         // testing for repeat cards. If repeat, regenerate both cards' suits
         boolean regened = false;
         while (regened == false) {
            regened = true;
            while ((cards[0] == cards[1]) & (numSuit1 == numSuit2)) {

               numSuit1 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               numSuit2 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               regened = false;
            }
            while ((cards[0] == cards[2]) & (numSuit1 == numSuit3)) {

               numSuit1 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               numSuit3 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               regened = false;
            }
            while ((cards[0] == cards[3]) & (numSuit1 == numSuit4)) {

               numSuit1 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               numSuit4 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               regened = false;
            }
            while ((cards[0] == cards[4]) & (numSuit1 == numSuit5)) {

               numSuit1 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               numSuit5 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               regened = false;
            }
            while ((cards[1] == cards[2]) & (numSuit2 == numSuit3)) {

               numSuit2 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               numSuit3 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               regened = false;
            }
            while ((cards[1] == cards[3]) & (numSuit2 == numSuit4)) {

               numSuit2 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               numSuit4 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               regened = false;
            }
            while ((cards[1] == cards[4]) & (numSuit2 == numSuit5)) {

               numSuit2 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               numSuit5 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               regened = false;
            }
            while ((cards[2] == cards[3]) & (numSuit3 == numSuit4)) {

               numSuit3 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               numSuit4 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               regened = false;
            }
            while ((cards[2] == cards[4]) & (numSuit3 == numSuit5)) {

               numSuit3 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               numSuit5 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               regened = false;
            }
            while ((cards[3] == cards[4]) & (numSuit4 == numSuit5)) {

               numSuit4 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               numSuit5 = (int) (Math.random() * 4) + 1;
               regened = false;
            }
         }

         // Switching number suits into words
         switch (numSuit1) {
         case 1:
            Suit1 = "Hearts";
            break;
         case 2:
            Suit1 = "Spades";
            break;
         case 3:
            Suit1 = "Diamonds";
            break;
         case 4:
            Suit1 = "Clubs";
            break;
         default:
            Suit1 = "Error Suit1";
         }
         switch (numSuit2) {
         case 1:
            Suit2 = "Hearts";
            break;
         case 2:
            Suit2 = "Spades";
            break;
         case 3:
            Suit2 = "Diamonds";
            break;
         case 4:
            Suit2 = "Clubs";
            break;
         default:
            Suit2 = "Error Suit2";
         }
         switch (numSuit3) {
         case 1:
            Suit3 = "Hearts";
            break;
         case 2:
            Suit3 = "Spades";
            break;
         case 3:
            Suit3 = "Diamonds";
            break;
         case 4:
            Suit3 = "Clubs";
            break;
         default:
            Suit3 = "Error Suit3";
         }
         switch (numSuit4) {
         case 1:
            Suit4 = "Hearts";
            break;
         case 2:
            Suit4 = "Spades";
            break;
         case 3:
            Suit4 = "Diamonds";
            break;
         case 4:
            Suit4 = "Clubs";
            break;
         default:
            Suit4 = "Error Suit4";
         }
         switch (numSuit5) {
         case 1:
            Suit5 = "Hearts";
            break;
         case 2:
            Suit5 = "Spades";
            break;
         case 3:
            Suit5 = "Diamonds";
            break;
         case 4:
            Suit5 = "Clubs";
            break;
         default:
            Suit5 = "Error Suit5";
         }

         // Switching card number into words
         switch (cards[0]) {
         case 1:
            card1s = "Ace";
            break;
         case 11:
            card1s = "Jack";
            break;
         case 12:
            card1s = "Queen";
            break;
         case 13:
            card1s = "King";
            break;
         default:
            card1s = "Error Card1s";
         }
         switch (cards[1]) {
         case 1:
            card2s = "Ace";
            break;
         case 11:
            card2s = "Jack";
            break;
         case 12:
            card2s = "Queen";
            break;
         case 13:
            card2s = "King";
            break;
         default:
            card2s = "Error Card2s";
         }
         switch (cards[2]) {
         case 1:
            card3s = "Ace";
            break;
         case 11:
            card3s = "Jack";
            break;
         case 12:
            card3s = "Queen";
            break;
         case 13:
            card3s = "King";
            break;
         default:
            card3s = "Error Card3s";
         }
         switch (cards[3]) {
         case 1:
            card4s = "Ace";
            break;
         case 11:
            card4s = "Jack";
            break;
         case 12:
            card4s = "Queen";
            break;
         case 13:
            card4s = "King";
            break;
         default:
            card4s = "Error Card4s";
         }
         switch (cards[4]) {
         case 1:
            card5s = "Ace";
            break;
         case 11:
            card5s = "Jack";
            break;
         case 12:
            card5s = "Queen";
            break;
         case 13:
            card5s = "King";
            break;
         default:
            card5s = "Error Card5s";
         }

         // Printing generated cards
         if ((cards[0] <= 10) & (cards[0] != 1))
            System.out.println("The first card is:  " + cards[0] + " of "
                  + Suit1);
         if ((cards[0] >= 11) | (cards[0] == 1))
            System.out
                  .println("The first card is:  " + card1s + " of " + Suit1);
         if ((cards[1] <= 10) & (cards[1] != 1))
            System.out.println("The second card is:  " + cards[1] + " of "
                  + Suit2);
         if ((cards[1] >= 11) | (cards[1] == 1))
            System.out.println("The second card is:  " + card2s + " of "
                  + Suit2);
         if ((cards[2] <= 10) & (cards[2] != 1))
            System.out.println("The third card is:  " + cards[2] + " of "
                  + Suit3);
         if ((cards[2] >= 11) | (cards[2] == 1))
            System.out
                  .println("The third card is:  " + card3s + " of " + Suit3);
         if ((cards[3] <= 10) & (cards[3] != 1))
            System.out.println("The fourth card is:  " + cards[3] + " of "
                  + Suit4);
         if ((cards[3] >= 11) | (cards[3] == 1))
            System.out.println("The fourth card is:  " + card4s + " of "
                  + Suit4);
         if ((cards[4] <= 10) & (cards[4] != 1))
            System.out.println("The fifth card is:  " + cards[4] + " of "
                  + Suit5);
         if ((cards[4] >= 11) | (cards[4] == 1))
            System.out
                  .println("The fifth card is:  " + card5s + " of " + Suit5);
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println();

         // Selection1 is part of the selecting which hand is desired program
         // The identification program runs only one of the Selections = RF
         Selection1 = "RF";
         // Identifying Royal Flush
         // Enter the while loop if all suits are the same
         while ((numSuit1 == numSuit2) & (numSuit1 == numSuit3)
               & (numSuit1 == numSuit4) & (numSuit1 == numSuit5)
               & (idcounter == 0) & (winner == 0)
               & (!Selection1.equalsIgnoreCase("DRF"))
               & (!Selection2.equalsIgnoreCase("DRF"))
               & (!Selection3.equalsIgnoreCase("DRF"))
               & (!Selection4.equalsIgnoreCase("DRF"))
               & (!Selection5.equalsIgnoreCase("DRF"))
               & (!Selection6.equalsIgnoreCase("DRF"))
               & (!Selection7.equalsIgnoreCase("DRF"))
               & (!Selection8.equalsIgnoreCase("DRF"))
               & (!Selection9.equalsIgnoreCase("DRF")))
         // Royal Flush identification
         {
            System.out.println("RF");
            if ((Selection1.equalsIgnoreCase("RF"))
                  | (Selection2.equalsIgnoreCase("RF"))
                  | (Selection3.equalsIgnoreCase("RF"))
                  | (Selection4.equalsIgnoreCase("RF"))
                  | (Selection5.equalsIgnoreCase("RF"))
                  | (Selection6.equalsIgnoreCase("RF"))
                  | (Selection7.equalsIgnoreCase("RF"))
                  | (Selection8.equalsIgnoreCase("RF"))
                  | (Selection9.equalsIgnoreCase("RF"))
                  | (Selection.equalsIgnoreCase("All"))) {
               if ((cards[0] == 1) & (cards[1] == 10) & (cards[2] == 11)
                     & (cards[3] == 12) & (cards[4] == 13) & (winner == 0)
                     & (numSuit1 == 1)) {
                  RES = "Hearts Royal Flush";
                  winner = winner + 1;
                  idcounter = idcounter + 1;
               }
               if ((cards[0] == 1) & (cards[1] == 10) & (cards[2] == 11)
                     & (cards[3] == 12) & (cards[4] == 13) & (winner == 0)
                     & (numSuit1 == 2)) {
                  RES = "Spades Royal Flush";
                  winner = winner + 1;
                  idcounter = idcounter + 1;
               }
               if ((cards[0] == 1) & (cards[1] == 10) & (cards[2] == 11)
                     & (cards[3] == 12) & (cards[4] == 13) & (winner == 0)
                     & (numSuit1 == 3)) {
                  RES = "Diamonds Royal Flush";
                  winner = winner + 1;
                  idcounter = idcounter + 1;
               }
               if ((cards[0] == 1) & (cards[1] == 10) & (cards[2] == 11)
                     & (cards[3] == 12) & (cards[4] == 13) & (winner == 0)
                     & (numSuit1 == 4)) {
                  RES = "Clubs Royal Flush";
                  winner = winner + 1;
                  idcounter = idcounter + 1;
               } else {
                  idcounter = idcounter + 1;
               }
            } else {
               idcounter = idcounter + 1;
            }
         }

      }
      System.out.println("We have a winner!");
      System.out.println("The winning hand is: " + RES);
      System.out.println("Counter:  " + counter);
      System.out.println("Press [Enter] to start over, enter [Exit] to quit.");
      YN = scn.nextLine();
   }
}
```

This is a part of my program made to randomly pick 5 cards, then find hands. This is the part of it used to find a Royal Flush. The program will run without error, but the loop sometime stops, not always, before it finds a Royal Flush.I did 4 test runs, only one of them found the Royal Flush @ 49964 loops, the rest of them stopped @ 7007, 74873 and 33228 loops.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Probably not related to your problem but have you considered using an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)?

Comment: Usually not enough code, _this time_ too much code. What is your condition that you want the loop to stop running? Royal Flush is very unlikely.

Comment: Holy wall of unformatted huge single main-method code, batman! Time to refactor. Use arrays, use methods, just get all that mess out of the one single main method. And please post only well formatted code. You want to make it easy for others to read your code and understand your problem, right?

Comment: I can not find the reason that it stops looping. :(

Comment: Yea I did thought of array, but I am still learning Java, not really used to that yet.

Comment: @CodeCamper The condition to stop is to have a winner (which will be defined as 1 whenever it finds a Royal Flush). The code is "while ((!YN.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) & (winner == 0))"   String YN is empty for the moment.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels :( sorry for the trouble, I am just a beginner. It is a lot of codes but the logic is kinda simple.

Comment: But again ,at least please put in the effort to present only well-formatted code. Please remember that you're asking volunteers for help, and I don't think it's asking too much of you to put in just a little more effort to make your code readable, do you? I've formatted your code for you, but please in the future, do this yourself. Many thanks in advance for your future efforts.

Comment: I like your way of generating cards ) what if all 5 cards will generate with the same number?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Apologies again, and Thank you for formatting. I will do my best to format these in the future.

Comment: @Salauyou Oh thanks for the advice, that might be it!

Comment: Probability of that is around 1/28500, similar to quantity of loops you run.

Comment: @Salauyou I just added some codes to prevent that. Running 5 of them at the same time. Haven't stop so far! I think that is it! Thanks a lot!!!!!

Comment: @Salauyou Thank you again! It worked! I used another while loop to prevent the 5 numbers to be the same XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability of getting 5 cards with the same value, using method you implemented, is ~1/28500. In such cases, your code tries to choose different suits for all 5 cards and falls into infinite `while` loop.

Comment: @user3527135: if this answered your question, you will want to "accept" the answer by clicking on the large check mark next to it. This will give Salauyou 15 well deserved reputation points.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I believe he's busy with calculating odds of getting all other combinations... So much code to type! :)

Comment: @Salauyou: indeed -- so inefficient! 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Really sorry man, I just figured out how to accept an answer. And yeah, I was testing for bugs :'(